# Remove the link from a Featured Image in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, slider

I have a slider that uses its images from the featured images in various posts.
When you click on the images on the slider they link back to the posts.
How do I remove the link altogether?  I dont want the slider images to link to anything.
Here is my code:

```
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() )the_post_thumbnail(array( 650,999 ),  array( 'alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title(), 'class' => 'slidethumb' )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The link is not made in this in your piece of code.
what does your source code say when you do this:

```
var_dump(get_the_post_thumbnail(
    array( 650,999 ),
    array( 'alt' => get_the_title(), 'title' => get_the_title(),'class' => 'slidethumb' )
)); die();
```

Comment: "<a href="mydomain" title=""><img width="150" height="150" src="../wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Slider-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-Culturesxslidethumb wp-post-image" alt="Slider" title="Slider" /></a>"

Comment: Somewhere there is a theme or plugin which causes this with a filter. To check this switch to a default theme and check again. after that turn off a plugin, check, turn off an other one. Untill you get what causes this.

Comment: its not a plugin.  Which WP file would be causing this?

Comment: If you turn off all plugins and switch to twentyten as theme. Does it still do this?

Comment: Do you see, in `functions.php` or elsewhere in a plugin code, one of the two examples in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Post_Thumbnail_Linking_to_the_Post_Permalink ? (there's a function in your text editor for searching in all files of a subdirectory a string like `has_post_thumbnail` or `'post_thumbnail_html'`)

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations Thank-you found the href in there and disabled it.  Much appreciated. How do I mark this answer as correct?

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations true, but then I would get the credits. Just copy your comment to a new answer so it can be accepted

Comment: @Felipe Alsacreations Can you please put your comment to new answer